# Retrieve props of each child in a loop to use a value as a key react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've two components (for simplicity I will call them `<List/>` and `<ListItem/>`) and the second one contains an `id` between its props. I have a loop inside the `<List/>` component (see below) where I need to assign a key to the ListItems I'm looping on. There is a way to retrieve the id of the single item inside the map function?

```
//App.jsx
<List>
  <ListItem id={adjsaiewwqa}/>
  <ListItem id={adssandsadn}/>
</List>

//List.jsx
<div className="css-classes">
 {props.children?.map(child => 
   <div key={/*HERE I WANT TO INSERT LIST ITEM ID*/} className="other-css-classes">
     {child}
   </div>
 }
</div>
```

**EDIT:** This problem came up because I was using ReactNode[] as the children type in react props. When the content of children is an array of Elements, React.Elements[] should be used instead.

After that props can be normally called on the child item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Your `List.jsx` should be:

```
 <div className="css-classes">
      {props.children?.map((child) => (
        <div key={child.props.id} className="other-css-classes">
          {child}
        </div>
      ))}
 </div>
```

If you are facing the following error using typescript is because the type of children should be `React.Element<MyPropsType>[]` and not `React.ReactNode[]`

```
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal'.
  Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string'.
```